# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048. Posting data from vue to laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I believe the answer to what I need is somewhere [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) but I somehow can't figure out what the problem is with my code.

I am trying to create an order details table after creating an order.
So I post the data to the endpoint from vue here.

```
createOrder: function() {
                this.$http.post('/api/orders', {
                    customer_id: this.form.customer.id,
                    items: _.map(this.cart, function(cart){
                        return {

   //these are the only values I need from the each item in the cart.

                            product_id: cart.id,
                            quantity: cart.quantity,
                            price: cart.price
                        }
                    })
                }).then(function(response) {
                    let responseBody = response.body;
                    this.$set('cart', []);
                    this.form.customer = {};
        });
```

then in the store method of the controller I want to collect the data, create an order, the create an order_details table using all the items in the cart.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

     $items = $request->input('items');

     $staff  = $request->user()->id;
     $customer = $request->input('customer_id');
     $status_id =  1;

     $order = new Order();
     $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $order->id_statuses = $status_id;
     $order->id_customers = $customer;
     //save order
     $order->save();



    foreach($items as $item){
        $order_detail = new OrderDetail();
        $order_detail->order_id = $order->id;
        $order_detail->id_products = $item->product_id;
        $order_detail->quantity = $item->quantity;
        $order_detail->price = $item->price;

        //save order detail
        $order_detail->save();

    }


    return response()->json($order);

}
```

In the traceback, all the values return null hence the db error I'm getting. My bet is I am not actually getting the items or properly accessing there properties.

Here is a shot of the payload if it helps. I'm also open to suggestions of better ways of posting the data so it's easier to work with as I am new to both these frameworks.

[image]

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 
Column 'id_products' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `order_details`           


(`order_id`, `id_products`, `quantity`, `price`, `updated_at`, 
 `created_at`) values (78, , , , 2016-12-30 17:18:04, 2016-12-30 17:18:04))
```

Comment: Check that all the items have a product_id.

Comment: Also share what you getting in `$items = $request->input('items');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of `id_products` is not coming here in $items variable.

Try with

```
$items = $request->items;
```

You need to provide value of `id_products` at least blank

**OR**

You should put default value

```
$table->integer('id_products')->default(0);
```

To change existing column use this

```
$table->integer('id_products')->default(0)->change();
```

You can't keep this blank without any default value in laravel 5.3

Comment: if I do that, order details can be submitted without having any products if am right.

Comment: I tried using $request->items as you suggested, same error.

Comment: please share `$request->$request` data  in `store` method ?

Comment: sorry how do I dump that please?

Comment: just put `return response()->json($request->$request)` as first line of method; you will get response as json

Comment: returns `No properties`

Comment: I did `return response()->json($request->items)` and got an array of objects containing the items

Comment: are you able to retrieve that `items` to loop in foreach may be you need to do json_decode here ,if necessary.

Comment: giving that a go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried accessing the properties of each object this way and it worked.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $items = $request->items;

    foreach ($items as $item){
        $order_detail = new OrderDetail();
        $order_detail->order_id = 99;
        $order_detail->id_products = $item['product_id'];
        $order_detail->quantity = $item['quantity'];
        $order_detail->price = $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];

        $order_detail->save();
    }
    return response("success");


}
```

Does anyone know why it had to be so?